# Literature on Riccati equations (algebraic and differential)

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

Advise me please some book on algebraic and differential Riccati equations: I'm interested in such questions as theorems of existence, uniqueness and extendibility of solutions of differential equation, explicit formulas for solutions and in related questions.

Comment: Have you had a look at the references in the Wikipedia article?  I can recommend Ince's book in particular.  Since I don't have the book in front of me at the moment, I can't say whether it covers all of the topics you're interested in.

Comment: What do you mean by "algebraic Ricatti equation"? I know it as a differential and as a difference equation, but not algebraic.

Comment: @vonbrand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation